# Catching undeclared CheckedException

Tags: java, exception

I'm using a third-party java library and this library class has a method called doSomething:

```
Library.doSomething();
```

In the course of the doSomething method, it sometimes throws a java.net.SocketException, but the doSomething method does not declare the SocketException as a checked exception. So when I try to write:

```
try {
    Library.doSomething();
} catch (java.net.SocketException error) {
    error.printStackTrace(); // and do other recovery stuff
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Unreachable catch block for SocketException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

However, I know that at runtime the doSomething method frequently throws the SocketException. I know that I can catch a generic java Exception and then check to see if it is a SocketException, but is there any more elegant way to catch the SocketExceptions thrown by this third party closed source library?

Thanks!

**Edit** - It turned out the SocketException is wrapped in a WebServiceException and I just missed the wrapped exception in a crowded error log. So there really isn't any question to answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I haven't downvoted - seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I do not believe you.  A Java method cannot throw a checked exception that it does not declare.  It is conceivable that you are running against a different version of the library than you build against -- in that case, the solution is to make those consistent.  Alternatively, perhaps the library declares its own, unchecked, `SocketException` in a different package, and you are confusing them.

Comment: @Mena, rethrowing does not provide a mechanism to defeat Java's invariant that checked exceptions thrown by a method are always declared.  That's a foundational principle.  Java 7+ applies more analysis to what checked exceptions actually can be thrown, and that can allow you to be more restrictive about what you declare, but that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: I looked into this a little more and I think that actually I was the one confused. It is a wrapped exception - the parent exception is a javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException which wraps a SocketException, so I should be able to catch the WebServiceException and everything will work correctly. Should I delete this whole question or do you think it still has value to anybody?

Comment: There is a suitable close reason for this case: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced"*. Since the problem you've described never really existed it is also hard to believe that other may get into the same confusion _and_ find this question. So in my opinion: yes you can delete this question (if possible, since there is already an accepted answer (which can be reverted)). This would also revert and lost/won reputation.

Comment: I just ran into this situation for real with a different library (which led me to this question).  However, since this specific question was due to a typo, I'm going to vote to close it as being due to a typo, since that feels like the correct action with regards to this specific question.  I do think it's valid, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mena's answer is very good, but I just want to state that there are ways (4 of them if I recall correctly, I mention them in the comments) to throw check exceptions that are not declared.

As a solution I suggest catching something general like Exception and check the type of the caught exception (using instanceof is recommended).

Comment: I would love to hear the ways that you claim a checked exception can be thrown from a method that does not declare it.  I would believe that it can arise from buggy native methods, and from mismatches between the classes relied upon at run time and those relied upon at compile time.  Did you have others?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sure. Top of my head, 1. make a constructor that throws a checked exception and invoke that constructor with reflection. 2. Use unsafe's throwException() 3. Thread's stop(throwable). The 4th was something with generics, declaring the exception as generic somehow, I never really knew that one :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not buying reflection, though.  If the reflected constructor throws, `Constructor.newInstance()` throws `InvocationTargetException`, not an undeclared checked exception.  On the other hand, `sun.misc.Unsafe.throwException()` is fair, though I'm going to put it in my "buggy native method" category because it violates its contract, even though that's intentional.  `Thread.stop(throwable)`, is the best example of the bunch, I think, despite being deprecated.  You've got me really curious (and doubtful) about the supposed way to do it with generics.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
catch (Exception e) {...}
```

Because compiler returns error if the catch block will never (or hardly ever) execute. In the catch block, you can compare the Exception using "instanceof" statement to get an information about specific exception.

Comment: OP is aware of that and asking for alternatives. Although IMO there's probably none.

Comment: what the hell is OP @Mena ?

Comment: @AndreFerraz **O**riginal **P**oster :)

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can catch a generic java Exception and then check to see if it is a SocketException, but is there any more elegant way to catch the SocketExceptions thrown by this third party closed source library?

There is no alternative that will actually deal with the exception; i.e. allow you to actually handle it in the normal fashion.

Basically, the 3rd-party library has broken Java's checked exception rules.  It is faulty and should be fixed.

---

FWIW, the code to work around the 3rd-party library bug is a "delicate":

```
try {
    callNastyMethod();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
        // handle the exception we are expecting
    } else if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
        // unexpected runtime exceptions should be rethrown 
        throw (RuntimeException) ex;
    } else {
        // deal with any other checked exceptions; for example.
        throw AssertionError("Unexpected checked exception", ex);
    }
}
```